# writing blank values as to start at column 2

Tags: python, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am scraping data, however I want the csv to write at column 2 to 12 or B-L rather than 1-4. Thus far I have simply been scraping langs_text to the column though this is slow.  Is there a better method that does not take such a long time so I can start at column 2?

I have tried to include the below however it simply does not write any values to csv and continues job.

E.g

```
langs11 = ("potato")
langs11_text = []



   langs11 = []
    langs11_text = []

    time.sleep(0)
    FILE LOCATION = 'C:\\Users\\Bain3\\Aperture.csv'

    with open((FILE LOCATION), 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        for row in zip(langs11_text, langs_text, langs11_text, langs11_text, langs11_text, langs11_text, langs1_text, langs2_text, elem_href, langs11_text):
            print(row)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see any benefit to this.  Scrape 1-x and adjust any other documentation to accommodate this.  Simpler yet, scrape one single element to the columns.  Much simpler.

Comment: @Wman Hadn't thought of that.  I'll try that now.  While not the solution I was after, that's certainly easier and just as good if it works.

Comment: Looks like I'll be redesigning a large portion of my job.  I guess that's not exactly fun considering the workload, but unavoidable.

Comment: @HaydenDarcy, do you just want to change order of columns while writing? If so why not use blank elements in array?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Can you show me how to do that?  I've tried to implement something similar but when I do it tends to not like it and just navigate to webpage and not write to csv.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Something like for row in zip("st", langs3_text, langs_text) should work in theory but it tends to create blank csv or severely shortened csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something like below

```
for row in zip(langs_text, langs2_text, langs3_text):
    data = ["","","","","","","","","","","",""]
    data[1] = row[0]
    data[4] = row[1]
    data[6] = href
    data[7] = row[2]

    writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: It does not like href as well as other errors I seem to be getting when I apply this to other jobs... https://pastebin.com/7MSwa8kX

Comment: This time you need to use `writer.writerow(data + [url1])` because now we are not using the original `row` tuple, instead we are using our own list `data`

Comment: Seems to be a discrepancy https://ibb.co/eNYrhb  between what my desired output is and what gets put in excel.

Comment: What I gave you is just a direction, you need to adjust indexes and what goes in loop/zip for this to work

Comment: Yeah I figured that!  Thanks for your help you saved me hours of having to redo up excels to fit the scrape.